# Applying a log function in a data frame

Tags: r, function, vectorization, transformation, logarithm

I'm trying to change the values inside a dataframe in R by applying log transformation.

My dataframe is only consisting of numeric values. When I apply this function

```
logFunct <- function(x) log10(x)
dim(data.frame(logFunct(df))
```

everything works well (i.e. 20 columns and 20 rows of dataframe will be returned as 20 columns and 20 rows new dataframe).

However, when I tried to account for zero values with this function (I know, it's probably an ugly function):

```
log4Zero <- function(x) ifelse(x!=0, log10(x+0.00000000001), log10(1))
dim(data.frame(log4Zero(df))
```

I got 400 columns x 20 rows and the zero values were catched as non-zero (returned -11 instead of 0).

Anyone can please explain what is happening here and how can I solve this (i.e. getting zero values as zero and anything else added and logged)?

Comment: why not use `log(x+1)` generally?

Comment: my values are pretty low, a lot of them are like below 0.0001. But the idea is the same I believe.

Comment: That doesn't really matter if you transform the results back after your computations

Comment: @docendodiscimus Better yet, use `log1p`.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Rui Barradas' answer above- use `log1p`.

Very important to note- your solution above returns `log(x+1)` only for initial scores of 0 and `log(x+1e-11)` for everything else. This gives you:

```
log4Zero(0) ~= log4Zero(1)
log4Zero(0) >> log4Zero(1e-10)
```

0 is much closer to 1e-10 than it is to 1. But after transformation, your observations of exactly 0 will be much, much higher than your observations of 1e-10. I am almost certain this is not what you want.

Using some dummy data:

```
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(400,5,1), nrow=20))
df[1,1] = 0
df[2,1] = 1e-10
log1p(df)
```

When I run `log4Zero(df)`, it returns a list of length 400, not a data frame. This is because `ifelse()` is already vectorized. So if you pass it an entire data frame, it is not taking `x` to be each entry of the data frame, but rather each column. From a data frame of dimensions `r` by `c`, it will return a list of length `r * c`, with each entry either being a transformed column (`log10(x+0.00000000001)`) or a single value (`log10(1)`)

If you do want to apply a function using `ifelse()`, use `apply()` instead:

```
logNew = function(x) ifelse(x!=0, log10(x), NA)
apply(df, 2, logNew)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide an example, it would be great. However if I have understood the problem well your data.frame reduces its dimensions. According to the example that I put here below that should not happen. The second function is correct. I give you an example of how to apply it so there are no problems. Hope that helps:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(0, sample(0:14, size = 14)), ncol = 5))

df %>% 
  mutate_all(., ~ ifelse(.!=0, log10(.+0.00000000001), log10(1)))
```